# Asset Catalog and Media Library Access and Naming Issues

Tags: ios, xcode, image, assets

Hey there stackoverflow!

This is probably actually a really stupid question, but I'm going to ask anyway, because why not.

So I made an app mockup in Sketch, and exported the images. All good, fine, dandy. When I import the images into XCode (still in their respective folders), still - good, fine, dandy. When I try to drag and drop an image from the media library picker in Storyboard; I'm running into a problem.

In Sketch, I used symbols and had some states that were organized, Ex. 'Icons/Toggle/Blue/On' and 'Icons/Toggle/Blue/Off'. The problem is, if I also had a 'Icons/Toggle/Red/On', Media Library is putting all of the 'On' images in one... asset, I suppose?

I can *see* the images in the media library if I click on the 'On' asset, but I can't choose one to place onto the storyboard view, or even just drag and drop that asset.

[image: Media Library picker showing all the options of the 'Activated' name]

Even worse - when I use 'provide namespace' in the assets picker, I can clearly see the images separating:

[image: Xcassets using provide namespace; peep the media library, all nice and organized]

But when I go back to the storyboard - poof! Gone. And once again,  *all grouped together*.

[image]

So - anyone know how to just pick a single image from the long list or will I have to rename everything or... is there some sort of trick?

EDIT: Just to add, I did a clean and a build run; still cannot see the images in Media Library or drag and drop them.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Though a clean and build run did not work (nor did closing the project/XCode and opening it up again), a full system reset seemed to have done the trick?

So maybe not solved but. Solvedish.